# Demoing android app screenshots

Tags: android, prototype, demo

I need a way to show off concept designs of an android application on an android phone to simulate that it is running. Basically just being able to tap to advance to the next photo/screen would be sufficient with a tap ANYWHERE on the screen. Any tools you know that would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is there any other option that does not involve any code?`

The easiest way I can think of is:
1. Take screen shots(wireframes, screen prototypes) for every screen flow you wish to demonstrate.
2. add them in proper sequence(regulated by sequence number) to your sdcard.
3. Open Picture gallery and use swipe gesture to transition and cycle between screen, walk through all the screen flows.

Comment: I need a way to not use swipe but tap on the picture instead to move to the next picture.

Comment: Just tap more than you swipe. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse with Android toolkit. 
Write a small program. wont take up much time.

[update]

No coding is required. Create an android project Using Eclipse android project, you can visually create UI prototype (i.e. drag and drop .. no coding). Use main.xml after developing each screen run the project in emulator, you can take screenshot of the same (either using eclipse DDMS plugin's snapshot capability or using Alt+Print screen in windows or something similar in other OS). Use this screenshot in a powerpoint presetation . Repeat the same process for a second screen (overwrite the same main.xml so that you dont have to write code). take screenshot again. Add the required animations in powerpoint.

Comment: @anton2g added extra content to answer

Comment: Is there a good application that allows to view powerpoint presentations on a phone and tap to go to the next slide? Google docs is close but when you tap to go to the next slide you sometimes get a blue or green overlay for a second to show that it was selected (not something I want).

Comment: @anton2g Not sure if there are good tools for slideshow. HTML based slideshow will be an option. But then again, you want to avoid coding. The eclipse method is easier than you think and the software dont cost

Answer (score 0):

Do it photoshop, create images, add it to an activity. Create a layout that fills the parent, add it as a background. Then implement a ontouch method to finish the activity and load the next. Quite simple.

Comment: Is there any other option that does not involve any code? Or is that the only way to go?